# Trouble deploying Laravel Passport with Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: sql, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, laravel-passport

I have successfully deployed and maintained a **Google App Engine + Laravel Project** using **Google Cloud SQL as a database**. I'm using Cloud Build to deploy, however on manual deployment my problem occurs just the same. I'm trying to get the locally working Laravel Passport installation to work on Google App Engine.

**Laravel Passport needs to run `php artisan passport:install`** in order to generate it's encryption keys and stow them into the database.
The only slot where this is possible in the GAE automatic build process is in `"post-install-cmd":[]` in **composer**, however at that stage the database connection is not established yet. => SQL Error while running `passport:install`

## **However**

I have also tried SSHing into the App Engine Instance and running `passport:install` manually, chmod'ing the storage directory to 0600, chown'ing the required **passport encryption keys** to **www-data** and yet I still get the following error:

`LogicException
Key path "file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable`

I am at a lack of options now and sadly cannot find a reference where Laravel Passport has been deployed to a GAE Project.

**What I'm looking for** is another viewpoint of what might be going wrong. Am I missing something with permissions that's specific to Google App Engine?
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got the same issue and  this [solution](https://qiita.com/hibohiboo/items/526566ffa007fe1ec84b) worked for me. please translate in english as the content on this site is in chinese.

**Put passport settings in environment variables**

**Creating a configuration file.**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-config
```

**Embed file contents in environment variables**

```
php artisan passport:install
```

The following files are created in

> storage/oauth-private.key
>
> storage/oauth-private.key

**Put the contents of this key file in the configuration file as follows**

```
//app.yaml
runtime: php72

env_variables:
  APP_KEY: YOUR_APP_KEY
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  ## Set these environment variables according to your CloudSQL configuration.
  DB_DATABASE: YOUR_DB_DATABASE
  DB_USERNAME: YOUR_DB_USERNAME
  DB_PASSWORD: YOUR_DB_PASSWORD
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME"
+   PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY: |
+     -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
+     <private key here>
+     -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
+   PASSPORT_PUBLIC_KEY: |
+     -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
+     <public key here>
+     -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
sudo chown www-data:www-data storage/oauth-*.key
sudo chmod 600 storage/oauth-*.key
sudo chown www-data:www-data oauth-public.key
sudo chmod 600 oauth-public.key
```

Comment: This may provide a solution, but please also add some explanation as to why this works.